# Editing a text file and commit after any change in the SVN tags (Subversion)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have a text file a.txt in the trunk which captures some information about tags. I want to update this a.txt and commit to the server whenever there is a change in the tags.

Is it possible from the server side (From post commit hook) or client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`svnlook dirs-changed -r %2 %1`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.dirs-changed.html) in the post-commit hook script to get the list of changed directories (it's either property change on the directory itself or changed child items),
2. Parse the output of the above command. If changed directories include `/tags` then modify a.txt file and either do an additional commit with the change to the repo via `file://` access method.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do it in hook (but it will be additional commit into `/trunk`)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide some link which shows how to do that?